# ADO / DataBase - How to get value that is in the same row but in other column that are finded values?

Tags: database, excel, vba, ms-access, ado

I have two range: qqq, where are 4 columns: IdTask, Line, Task, Frequency and in different sheet dane with 2 columns: IdTask, Date. In qqq in columns are values and dane are empty.

```
qqq:
IdTask |Line|Task|Frequency
  1    | L1 | Abs| Weekly
  2    | L5 | Des| Daily

dane:
IdTask|Date
      |   
      |
```

I want to work this way: when I pick a value from listbox (where are two columns: Line and Task) to find this Line and Task in "qqq". Then find/select/copy value from IdTask column what is in the same row what finded Line and Task. After this go to "dane" and in column IdTask paste chosen IdTask and in date today's date (with day ended at 6).

I have trouble with finding IdTask for chosen Line and Task.

I will be thankful for any suggestion, I'm new with ADO.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim LDate As Date
    Dim MDate As Date
If Time > TimeValue("00:00:00") And Time < TimeValue("06:00:00") Then
    LDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Now)
Else
    LDate = Now
End If
    MDate = DateValue(LDate)     
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\plkmxm08\Desktop\MMS.xlsm;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"";"
     rst.Open "SELECT [LINE], [TASK], [Frequency], qqq.[IdTask FROM qqq LEFT JOIN dane _
     ON qqq.[IdTask] =  dane.[IdTask];", cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, _
     adCmdTableDirect
       rst.Filter = "Line= '" & Me.ListBox1.List(lItem, 0) & "' And Task = '" & Me.ListBox1.List(lItem, 1) & "'" 
        cnn.Execute "INSERT INTO dane([IdTask],[Date]) VALUES('" & IdTask & "','"&MDate&"');"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain a little clearer? `WHERE` rather than filter, also you can say `INSERT INTO [X] SELECT [Z] FROM [Y] WHERE [X].[Field]='value'`

Comment: I edited describe - I hope it will be clearer.
Thank you for the suggestion, I will check it out.

Comment: I tried
`cnn.Execute "INSERT INTO dane([IdTask]) SELECT qqq.[IdTask] FROM qqq WHERE Line= '" & Me.ListBox1.List(lItem, 0) & "' And Task = '" & Me.ListBox1.List(lItem, 1) & "'"`
There isn't any error but it doesn't work anyway. This doen't change my base in range "dane".